# How to get rid of empty space around the border of Image

Tags: html, css, image, background, space

I want to make the image to fully right and top side of the screen.

```
body{
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
background: #822B2B;
color: #ffffff;
overflow: hidden; }


#showcase{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
text-align: center;
/* margin-left: 116px; */
/* width: 180vh; */
height: 100vh;

background: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/1402787/pexels-photo-1402787.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260') no-repeat center center / cover; }
```

Please feel free to ask anything in need of clarification.
Code at: https://codepen.io/zaidik/pen/WNQYbXz

Comment: Can you post the HTML so we can see the context of your CSS

Comment: I got the solution, I just needed to include margin: 0; in the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `margin:0;` to your body CSS rules

Comment: Thank you so much man. It solved my problem!